# Embed Maps using TWebGoogleMaps

Tags: delphi, maps, tms, tms-web-core

I am attempting to embed a map into a TWebGoogleMaps however I am unable to do this, when I try using the Latitude and Longitude properties then I got this message.[image: Error Message(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghwi6.png)]

Does anyone perhaps know how to embed a map using TMS TWebGoogleMaps

I tried using the Google Maps embed HTML link
as well as the Latitude (30°34'19"S) and Longitude (30°34'24"E) properties then I got this message.

Comment: You need to show the code that produces that error message. The general rule is, that you need to provide a [mre] so that anybody who attempt to help you, can reproduce the error situation. Please edit your question to add the code.

Comment: You are using wrong format for Latitude and Longitude values. As error states the component expects a simple floating point value but you are trying to set text `30°34'19"S`. Instead you should do `-30.3419` for Latitude (negative value because it is on southern hemisphere) and `30.3424` for Longitude (it is positive since it is on eastern side). Also when you right click on google maps website and copy Latitude/Longitude into clipboard it seems that google maps is using Double precision floating point numbers.